# Salt master cannot run state on minion

Tags: salt-stack

When I run $salt minion_name.domain.com state.highstate I get this error:

```
minion_name.domain.com
    Data failed to compile:

    Pillar failed to render with the following messages:

    No matching pillar environment for environment 'floating' found
```

Anybody has any idea please?

===============================================================

Actually I found why I was getting this error. in our minion, 2 masters have been defined.

master:

- master1.domain.com
- master2.domain.com

If I comment one and restart salt-minion, it works. But with having 2 minions, I get that weird error. This is happening only for one minion. Other minions work fine with multiple master defined. I don't know why!

Comment: Run the command with `-l debug` to get more info about what fails. Since the `highstate` may contain several states (and ID's with them), it is practiacally impossible to answer the question with the presented information.

Comment: @ansi_lumen
Thanks. It seems there is an issue with multiple master defined on minion. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was multiple salt-minion instances running on minion server (AIX). I killed them all and restarted salt-minion service (salt-minion -d) and got what I wanted.